# jquery button click to act on specific div children

Tags: jquery, children

I have a set of buttons, when they're clicked I want the first child to have the css display none, and the second child to have the css display block, for all of the buttons, it's not quite working, this is what I have.

JS:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  $(".btn:nth-child(2)").css ({
    display: "none"
  });
  $(".btn:nth-child(1)").css ({
    display: "block"
  });  
});
```

the structure of the .btn

```
<div id="bow" class="btn" data-filter=".bow">
  <img class="filter_icon" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/icons/bow_icon.png" alt="">
  <img class="filter_icon not_selected" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/icons/bow_icon_selected.png" alt="">  
</div>
```

Comment: Per your description your `:nth-child(1)` and `:nth-child(2)` are reversed.  You want your first child to be `display:none` but you have `nth-child(2)` set to `display:none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
  $(this).find("img:nth-child(1)").css ({
    display: "none"
  })
  .end()
  .find("img:nth-child(2)").css ({
    display: "block"
  });  
});
```

Comment: wham bam yes that's the answer, thanks.  why does it have to specifically indicate img?

Comment: also, how would you do the same thing, except instead of the .btn class using this?

Comment: Because [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) finds the `nth` child that matches the selector, so before you were searching for the nth `.btn` not the nth child of `.btn`. (Already updated to use `this`)

Comment: for the updated answer, why do you have to put .end()?  why can't you just go right to the second find?

Comment: @loriensleafs Because [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) changes the matched set to match a new selector, so [`.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end) reverts it to the original before doing the next `.find`.